# Is this possible with Gulp? Gulp Change Text and Dest

Tags: javascript, gulp

I don't know what this is possible.

**files**

```
a.html / b.hml
c.css / d.css
```

1. There are two changes in Html and Css
2. Each HTML has a changed Css(c.css,d.css).
3. The path of Css is as follows

---

```
<link src="/style/sample/c.css">
```

---

1. If a Css file has been changed, verify that the CSS file has been declared in the changed HTML.
2. Change the path of the css file.
3. Create a new file using Gulf's dest.

---

That's my code here.

```
async function ds(cd) {
const branch = branchName.replace("/", "-");
let fileHtml = [],
  fileCSS = [],
  fileImage = [];
  
// npm package git-status,
// Look for files that are up on git stage.
await gitStatus((err, data) => {
  data.map((e) => {
    item = e.to.replace("WebContent/resources", "./resources"); // change path
    // Check only Resources
    if (item.indexOf("./resources/") !== -1) {
      if (item.indexOf("html") !== -1) {
        fileHtml.push(item); // get Html List T^T
        return fileHtml;
      }

      if (item.indexOf("css") !== -1) {
        // css
        fileCSS.push(item);
        return fileCSS;
      }

      if (item.indexOf("img") !== -1) {
        // img
        fileImage.push(item);
        return fileImage;
      }
    }
  });
  cd();
});

//I think it's possible with JavaScript, but I don't know what to do with Gulp.
fileHtml.forEach((e) => {
  let files = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + e, "utf8"); //해당 HTML 파일
  let splitFile = files.split(/\r?\n/);

  // 각각의 HTML 파일 내부에서
  let result = splitFile.forEach((j, i) => {
    // 위에서 찾은 css 파일이 있는지 찾아서
    fileCSS.forEach((v) => {
      if (j.indexOf(v) >= 0) {
        let result = j.replace("/resources/", "/" + branch + "/");
        console.log(result);
        // console.log("페이지는", e);
        // console.log("파일은", v);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

}

Comment: It's possible. But what problem are you trying to solve with this workflow? And why are you renaming CSS files after every change? If you need to document the file has been updated, can you do that with a CSS comment instead and leave the filename, and therefore path, the same?

Comment: @Sean

first of all my workspace have problem that image folder is so Large

It is a system that uploads the completed HTML source to the View server and receives confirmation.

It takes a very long time to upload all the folders.

Therefore, I want to check whether the modified CSS, image file is used within the modified HTML file, upload only that to a specific folder, and change the path to that folder.